# помогите скомпилировать py в exe с папками и медиа-файлами в них?

Tags: python, python-3.x

мне нужно скомпилировать вот это всё в один ехе
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая штука: `auto-py-to-exe`. Устанавливается с помощью `pip`. Затем в cmd / terminal пишешь `auto-py-to-exe` и у тебя откроется веб интерфейс, где на английском тебе всё написано. Выбираешь что надо ну и всё

Comment: не сработало, есть только autopytoexe

Comment: @pupsikvay https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/ — подозреваю, что `autopy2exe` поменяли на `auto-py-to-exe`

Comment: да, так и есть, извиняюсь за ошибку